# How can I save the result of a script ( in text file) in Jenkins to be used for the next run?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, writetofile

Currently I have a pipeline which accepts a token and successfully executes the script.after the script is executed, a new token will be generated and I want that token to be saved ( in a text file preferably)
As of now, the script runs successfully and updates the token file when executed from eclipse but from pipeline, the token is initially picked but not updated ( after execution) Is there a way we can update or save it in a different file? Any format is fine.